# Preimage of $f(x)=\text{sign}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Find the required preimage of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\text{sign}(x)$. Find $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.

For which open subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is $f^{-1}(U)$ not open?

So the answer from the textbook
to this is the following:

$f^{-1}(\{1\})=(0,\infty)$

$f^{-1}(U)$ is not open if $U$ contains zero and not both of $+1$ and $-1$.

First question: $U$ can be $(-1,1)$, am I right?

(Continuation of the answer)

Otherwise it is one of $\emptyset, (0,\infty),(-\infty,0)$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, all of which are open.

Second question: I am not sure what this last line is supposed to answer to be honest. If you could clarify this, I would be grateful.

Comment: I am not sure I understand: those are your answers and you're asking if they are correct?

Comment: @tommy1996q no sorry, those are the answers from the textbook

Comment: use the definition of preimage to see what is $f^{-1}((-1,1))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $U = (-1, 1)$ is an example such that $U$ is open and $f^{-1}(U) = \{0\}$, which is not open.

The second part of the answer seems to be trying to list the possibilities when $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, but misses one out.

Here is how prove both parts: assume $U$ is open and let $V = U \cap \{-1, 0, 1\}$. Then $f^{-1}(U)$ will be: $\emptyset$, if $V = \emptyset$; $(0, \infty)$, if $V = \{1\}$; $(-\infty, 0)$, if $V = \{-1\}$; $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, if $V = \{-1, 1\}$ and $\Bbb{R}$, if $V = \{-1, 0, 1\}$ (the case which is missing from the given list).

The only other possibilities for $V$ are $\{0\}$, $\{-1, 0\}$ and $\{0, 1\}$, (these are the cases when $U$ contains $0$ but not both of $-1$ and $1$). In those three cases $f^{-1}(U)$ will not be open: it will be $\{0\}$, $(-\infty, 0]$ or $[0, \infty)$.